# Using Apple Music's "Up Next" feature from search

Tags: mac, itunes, music, monterey, search

I'm using macOS Monterey v12.6.1.

In Apple Music, I can search for a term and it displays many songs that match with this term. How can I play all the songs in this list one after the other as if it were its own playlist? Apple Music used to have this capability in earlier versions of Mac OSX, but I am no longer aware of how to do this.

I do *not* want to make a new playlist.

A potential solution is to manually add all the songs that show up in search to "Playing Next". However, it doesn't let me select any songs from within the search results - I cannot right-click, CMD-A, nor "Edit>Select-All". The only songs I seem to be able to add to "Playing Next" are from within an already-existing playlist.

[image: no upcoming songs]